# Does regretting a good deed void it?

Tags: fiqh, deeds

If one performed a good deed with pure intentions then regretted it afterwards does that deed become invalid and no reward is received for it?

**For example:** you lend someone money and then later you end up being short on cash and think that it may have been better to hold on to what you had instead or it could be that you discover that the person you lent the money to used it for facilitate sin.